# Cannot find module 'reactcomponent'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp

Please I am stuck

I am web developer used to generate html from the backend

Just switching to react and seems like a pain in the ...

[image: structure]

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "ps-full-stack",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "authors": [
    "radu.hulubas <razorflashmedia>"
  ],
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.1.0"
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ps-full-stack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^8.0.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.24.7",
    "browserify": "^16.2.2",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-live-server": "0.0.31",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

main.jsx

```
var itemlist = require('./components/itemlist');
React.render(<itemlist/>, app);
```

The error I am getting is -

> *Error: Cannot find module './components/itemlist'*  -

which makes no sense, since the path is correct

Comment: Show us ItemList please

Comment: `var React = require('react/addons');

module.exports = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Grocery Listify</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
});`

Comment: How about trying `var itemlist = require('./components/itemlist.jsx');`

Comment: Thank you very much @Leo Odishvili - much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with badly written require statement.

This:

```
var itemlist = require('./components/itemlist');
```

Should be change by this:

```
var itemlist = require('./components/itemlist.jsx');
```

Answer (score 0):

**main.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = new express();

const PORT = 7777;
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.render('./../app/index.ejs',{});
})
  .use(express.static(__dirname + '/../.tmp'))
  .listen(PORT);
```

**itemlist.jsx**

```
var React = require('react/addons');

module.exports = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Grocery Listify</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

gulp.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var LiveServer = require('gulp-live-server');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
let path = require('path');

gulp.task('live-server',function(){
  var server = new LiveServer('server/main.js');
  server.start();
});

gulp.task('bundle',function(){

  return browserify({
    entries: 'app/main.jsx',
    debug: true,
  })
    .transform(reactify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./.tmp'))
    ;
});

gulp.task('serve',['bundle','live-server'], function(){
  browserSync.init(null,{
    proxy:"http://localhost:7777",
    port: 9001,
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your itemList component to this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class ItemList extends Component {
  render() {
     return (
        <div> <h1>Grocery Listify</h1> </div>
     )
  }
}
```

And in your Main file import it like this :

```
import ItemList from './components/itemlist'
```

Comment: that would require to use babelify I think - I used reactify. look up gulp.js

but even so it will not work